# How to combine rows and columns?

Tags: sql, join, union

I have two tables. I need to combine two table.

This  First table.

```
   ----------------------------
   | row_no | Part No |Qty_A   |
   ----------------------------
   | 1      |    A    | 100    |
   | 2      |    A    | 300    |
   ----------------------------
```

Second table.

```
   ----------------------------
   | row_no | Part No |Qty_B   |
   ----------------------------
   | 1      |    A    | 400    |
   | 2      |    B    | 200    |
   ----------------------------
```

This is my result:

```
   --------------------------------------
   | row_no | Part No |  Qty_A |  Qty_B   |
   --------------------------------------
   | 1      |    A    | 100    |   400    |
   | 2      |    A    | 300    |    -     |
   | 2      |    B    |   -    |   200    |
   --------------------------------------
```

Two tables was joined by **"row_no"** and **"Part_no"** column.
I try to use "LEFT OUTER JOIN" but results not as expected.

```
SELECT t1.row_no ,t1.part_no ,t1.Qty_A ,t2.Qty_B
FROM
(SELECT 1 as row_no,'A' as part_no,100 as Qty_A) as t1
 LEFT OUTER  JOIN 
(SELECT 1 as row_no, 'B' as part_no,200 as Qty_B) as t2
   ON t1.row_no = t2.row_no and t1.part_no = t2.part_no
```

Sorry for my unclear example.

**Update** 
This is example from a large transaction.
[image]

And I need to group it by Part_no and re-arrange by row number like these.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell the desired output?

Answer (score 3):

Try below query with union all:

```
select row_no ,part_no ,Qty_A , '-' as Qty_B from tableA
union all
select row_no ,part_no ,'-' as Qty_A , Qty_B from tableb
```

or you can try with full outer join:

```
SELECT t1.row_no ,t1.part_no ,t1.Qty_A ,t2.Qty_B
FROM
(SELECT 1 as row_no,'A' as part_no,100 as Qty_A) as t1
 full OUTER  JOIN 
(SELECT 1 as row_no, 'B' as part_no,200 as Qty_B) as t2
   ON t1.row_no = t2.row_no and t1.part_no = t2.part_no
```

Answer (score 2):

The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.
 - Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of
   columns
 - The columns must also have similar data types
 - The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order
The first query in the union statement defines the column names.
So in your case you could

```
select row_no ,part_no ,Qty_A , null as Qty_B  from table1
union all
select row_no ,part_no , null, Qty_B from table2
```

Comment: The first query in the `union` statement defines the column names.

Comment: But I think UNION will combine without the key.